# How can I make page anchors case-insensitive?

Tags: jquery, html

With jQuery, how can I make anchor URL segments of any case work with the page's anchors and `id`s? For example, `examples.com#AnChOr` should scroll to either `a[name="anchor"]` or `div[id="ANCHOR"]`, whichever it finds first (this, of course, presumes we have non-ambiguous anchors on the page).

Comment: You can't without looping every `a[name]` and `div[id]`... Which is kind of demanding

Comment: But it's only done once on page load. Anchor scrolling is never instantaneous anyway, even in modern browsers, so a few more milliseconds shouldn't matter.

Comment: Fine, but with that information, do you still need an answer or you're ok? I'd suggest you look up a bit, try something then show us what you've tried.

Comment: That was my intention, but since I didn't post the answer right with the question, I have to wait two days to accept it now... Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Wait for images to load for proper offsets
$(window).load(function() 
{
    // Compare lowercase hashes
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1).toLowerCase();

    // Check IDs
    $('[id]').each(function()
    {
        if ($(this).attr('id').toLowerCase() === hash)
        {
            $(window).scrollTop($(this).offset().top);
        }
    });

    // Check named anchors
    $('a[name]').each(function()
    {
        if ($(this).attr('name').toLowerCase() === hash)
        {
            $(window).scrollTop($(this).offset().top);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why are you using `$(function() {..}` and `$(window).load`?

Comment: You're right, window will be defined before the DOM is loaded. Editing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can control the case of the actual name/id values, you can just change the case of the location hash tag with a script, to alway set it to lower case (or upper case using .toUpperCase()):

```
window.location.hash = window.location.hash.toLowerCase();
```

If you really need to scan, here is a routine which will do it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    $('a[name], div[id]').each(function(i,e) {
        if(e.tagName =="A" && hash.toLowerCase()==e.name.toLowerCase()) {
            window.location.hash = '#'+e.name;
            return false;
        }
        else if(hash.toLowerCase() == e.id.toLowerCase()) {
            window.location.hash = '#'+e.id;
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a, i, m) {
return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
  .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};

// OVERWRITES old selecor
jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
.indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
</script>
```

Comment: What does this code even do? Could you add an explanation?